# Understanding Wyckoff Position of Apatite group

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

I was learning about Wyckoff position, and one of the simplest example was of $ZrO_{2}$. For Zr and O, the Wyckoff positions are 4a and 8c and belongs to space group Fm-3m. Now from the Wyckoff notation, one can check the stoichiometry of the compound. But in case of apatite, say $Ca_{5}(PO_{4})_{3}OH$, if see the Wyckoff positions, there are two different calcium atoms, 3 different oxygen atoms and one phosphorus atom and on hydrogen atom, where the two calcium atoms have 4f and 6h site, oxygen atoms have 6h, 6h and 12i site and phosphorous has 6h site and one oxygen and one hydrogen has 4e site. what do they actually represent and if we want to see if stoichiometry is maintained, how can we verify it?